# grant a view for a user filtred on a filed in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, view, permissions, sql-grant

Hi i have a view in oracle and i want grant each user for access a specific set of data, for example:

```
VIEW V
ID    column2   column3
1       P          C
1       A          B
2       G          H
1       B          L
2       G          T
```

i want that user U1 can view only:

```
ID    column2   column3
1       P          C
1       A          B
1       B          L
```

and USER U2 can view only:

```
ID    column2   column3
2       G          H
2       G          T
```

Is possible in oracle set this permission right?
THANKS
REGARDS

Comment: Ok, then you might be interested in Virtual Private Database-http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/apdvpoli.htm#i1009600

Comment: Then go to the referenced documentation and research whether that is the solution you were searching for.

Comment: no dont is this.. 
I need a statement like this: 
GRANT select on view1 to USER1 where ID=1;

Comment: Create views for each id and give access accordingly.

Comment: i can create N views like:
VIEW_G USER1
VIEW_G on USER2